# Defining reference of an object across the class level and assining the value in the constructor

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Why in many cases i see the coder define a reference of an object in the class level then he create the object it self (assign it's value) in the constructor ??

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Graphics grfx;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grfx = this.CreateGraphics();
    }
}
```

What is the benefits  of this. Is this allow us to access this object from any method in the class ??

Comment: Because the person wants `grfx` to have that value when an object of type `Form1` is constructed.

Comment: Yes, you got it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grfx` is an instance variable of `Form1`. It is defined on the class level (i.e. outside any method or a constructor), so all non-static methods of the class can access it.

One benefit to initializing it in the constructor is that the rest of the code can rely on it being set, avoiding the unnecessary `null` checks. In this case it is probably a good idea to make `grfx` private and read-only, to ensure that it is never set outside the constructor:

```
private readonly Graphics grfx;
```